# Building an array from two tables (getting images from one table for a product from the other)

Tags: php, mysql

OK I know this should be easy but i'm going round in circles. I have two tables, and two functions each running a query, the first function gets a product, the second one gets images for a product

I want to get an array which is the product, and it's images...

here's my code...

```
/**
 * Gets the requested product from the DB
 * 
 * @param string $productUrl
 * @param string $productID
 */
private function _db_get_product($productUrl = null, $productID = null) {

    if (empty($productUrl) && empty($productID))
        return;

    $db = $this->getConnection();
    $q = "SELECT " . $this->_leaf_sql_fields() . 
            " FROM content_products_items pr WHERE pr.productStatus >= "
            . menuMachine::getMinimumStatus() . " ";

    if (!empty($productUrl))
        $q .= " AND productUrl = '" . $productUrl . "'";

    if (!empty($productID))
        $q .= " AND productID = '" . $productID . "'";

    if ($res = $db->recordsetSingle($q))
        $this->_product = $res;

    return $res;
}

/**
 * Get the images for the product
 * @return array
 */
private function _db_get_product_images($productID) {

    $db = $this->getConnection();

    $q = "SELECT * FROM content_products_images WHERE productID = '" . $productID . "'";

    $this->_productImages = $db->recordset($q);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a query to combine the two within the same function?

```
//Basic query, improve it according to your needs

SELECT 
*
FROM
content_products_items  as p,
content_products_images as i
WHERE
p.productID = $productId AND
i.productID = p.productID;
```

Or for a way to call both functions and combine the results in a array?

```
$myProduct = array(
    'productData'   => $this->_db_get_product($productUrl, $productID),
    'productImages' => $this->_db_get_product_images($productID),
);
```

Both should guide you into a working direction.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at answering someone here on StackOverflow, so bear with me ... but I think the below is what you are looking for?

```
$product = array('product' => _db_get_product($URL, $ID), 'images' => _db_get_product_images($ID));
```

Alternately, if you want it all in one go and don't need the two separate methods for anything else, you could rewrite your _db_get_product method as follows:

```
private function _db_get_product($productUrl = null, $productID = null) {

    if (empty($productUrl) && empty($productID))
        return;

    $output = array();
    $db = $this->getConnection();
    $q = "SELECT " . $this->_leaf_sql_fields() . 
        " FROM content_products_items pr WHERE pr.productStatus >= "
        . menuMachine::getMinimumStatus() . " ";

    if (!empty($productUrl))
        $q .= " AND productUrl = '" . $productUrl . "'";

    if (!empty($productID))
        $q .= " AND productID = '" . $productID . "'";

    if ($res = $db->recordsetSingle($q))
        array_push($output, $res);

    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM content_products_images WHERE productID = '" . $productID . "'";
    array_push($output, $db->recordset($q2));

    return $output;
}
```